# Hadoop - Finding Unique Values in Text Files

Tags: java, hadoop

I've started to learn Hadoop in Java. I'm doing some exercises with WordCount sample.

Basically, I have 3 text files, the program reads the files and lists the word count, for instance;

```
the 2654
hadoop 23
stackoverflow 12
```

So forth so on.

I want to retrieve the unique words that appear in only one document. It means that if a word appear in TextFile1 but not appear in either TextFile2 and TextFile3, the program should write it in the output.

How can I do that? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide a link to that exercise?

Comment: Yes sir here it is, https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html. It is "Example: WordCount v1.0"

Comment: My approach would be to map words along with the file name in which that word was encountered.